# Discord API, can not get data from json array inside array from user input arg[1] in Node JS

Tags: node.js, json, discord

I am using Discord API on Node JS.

I got a JSON array and I am trying to get the client output the corresponding value for what the user typed inside a json array.

Inside the client.js

```
let name = (arg[1])
message.author.send('Result: ' + data.name.desc + data.name.code)
```

Inside the JSON:

```
{
   "Server1": {
    "desc": "A Fun Place",
    "code": "9021da"
    },
   "Server2": {
    "desc": "A Chill Place",
    "code": "90a11d"
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is giving the user the desc and the code of the server that they type.
(There are over 100 of these)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use bracket notation:

```
message.author.send('Result: ' + data[name].desc + data[name].code)
```